# Ajax POST not recognised as part of current guest session, Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a page that after opened, make a serie of ajax posts to a notification endpoint. I would like to persist data across the posts using a guest session. No login, but context control regardless. I am using cookies.

I am having issues to restore objects from the session is these ajax requests (they come null), and I noticed that on each post to the notification endpoint, I get a different value for `request()->session()->getId()`, which makes me think the session is not being communicated properly and that's why I don't see the objects I expected to see persisted.

My URLs are using the "web" middleware.

Everytime the page open I do:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>'
        }
    });
</script>
```

To ensure ajax requests will have the CSRF token in the header

I also do 'request()->session()->regenerate();'everytime the page opens (not in the notifications) to ensure a new session.

Is there anything else (perhaps pass values from cookies) that I should send in the POST to identify the request as part of a context?

Comment: Please can you show your code for this? i.e. your controller method and your ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make it stateless.

- Send a request from client to server
- The server generates and returns a "token"
- The client receives the token and stores this for example in local storage
- The client sends with each request the token as a header (or as parameter in URL)
- (the server checks the token from the header)

Advantage is your independency of session handling.

Comment: I did that using a milliseconds timestamp as token and solved my issue! Is there any "Laravel way" of generating some sort of more trustful token? Or should the CSRF take care of the security side and I can stick with the timestamp?

Comment: @PauloAmaral I prefer hashing with a key. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Answer (score 0):

```
        var _id     = 1011;
        var url     = "/test";

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            url: url,
            data: {id: _id},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){

            }
        });
```

Comment: That was one of my first attempts, unsuccessful btw. As per my research, the CSRF token has more to do with making client requests trustful, rather than making a session unique, right?

Comment: csrf token prevent csrf attacks

Comment: copy this code => <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">